# Python SQL cursor giving different results?

Tags: python, sqlite, python-2.x

I have the following function in Python:

```
def get_emo_results(emo, operator):
    cursor.execute("SELECT avg(?) FROM [LIWC Post Stats] "
                   "WHERE goals_scored {0} goals_taken "
                   "GROUP BY post_number "
                   "ORDER BY post_number ASC "
                   "LIMIT ?".format(operator), [emo, posts_limit])
    print "SELECT avg({1}) FROM [LIWC Post Stats] "\
            "WHERE goals_scored {0} goals_taken "\
            "GROUP BY post_number "\
            "ORDER BY post_number ASC "\
            "LIMIT {2}".format(operator, emo, posts_limit)
    return [x[0] for x in cursor.fetchall()]
```

I call it with `get_emo_results('posemo', '>')` and get this output to stdout:

```
SELECT avg(posemo) FROM [LIWC Post Stats] WHERE goals_scored > goals_taken GROUP BY post_number ORDER BY post_number ASC LIMIT 200
```

However, the function itself returns

```
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, ... 0.0]
```

I copy and paste that exact expression in stdout to my SQLite process that I have opened, and I get this:

```
1.8730701754386
2.48962719298246
2.18607456140351
2.15342105263158
2.33107456140351
2.11631578947368
2.37100877192982
1.95228070175439
2.01013157894737
...
3.37183673469388
```

So not 0 at all. Why does my Python function return something different despite using the same query? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**:

It now works when I get rid of the question marks and format the string directly. Why don't parameterized queries work in this case?

Comment: Are you sure the statement printed is the exact same as the query in cursor.execute?  There is a subtle difference in how you are formatting the string.  Does cursor.execute replace each ? with the corresponding clause from the list?

Comment: Are you connecting to a different database when you do it directly vs through python?

Comment: @ajon ahhh, you are right, it works when I format the string instead of doing a parameterized query...

Comment: @Gerrat no, I am sure its the same one, everything else works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is being handled differently because you are parametirzing your query.  You can't really parameterize a column name like that.  It is trying to protect you from SQL injection so it is (I'm simplifying here, but basically) encapsulating any strings in quotes before passing it to the SQL engine.

Essentially, SQLlite is trying to average the string literal 'posemo'

You can keep your limit parameterized, but when it comes to column names you need to have them hardcoded or else put them in the string with something like format.